# In VHDL, How to implement two tristate buffers driving the same pin with a PULLUP?

Tags: vhdl, verilog

In VHDL, How to implement two tristates driving the same pin with a pullup?  I tried to do the same thing in Verilog and it synthesizes without any problem:

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps

module driver(
    input  wire oe,
    input  wire di,
    output tri1 do
);
assign do = oe ? di : 1'bz;

endmodule

`timescale 1ns/10ps

module top(
    input  wire oe1,
    input  wire di1,
    input  wire oe2,
    input  wire di2,
    output tri1 do
);


driver driver1(
    .oe (oe1),
    .di (di1),
    .do (do)
);

driver driver2(
    .oe (oe2),
    .di (di2),
    .do (do)
);

endmodule
```

When I try to write this in VHDL, I get a little bit stuck because VHDL I'm not sure how to map Verilog's tri1 "pullup" into VHDL.

```
library ieee;
use     ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity driver is
    port(
        oe :in  std_logic;
        di :in  std_logic;
        do :out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of driver is
begin
    do <= di when (oe = '1') else 'Z';
end architecture;

library ieee;
use     ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity top is
    port(
        oe1 :in std_logic;
        di1 :in std_logic;
        oe2 :in std_logic;
        di2 :in std_logic;
        do  :out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of top is
begin

    driver1: entity work.driver
        port map(
           oe => oe1,
           di => di1,
           do => do
        );

    driver2: entity work.driver
        port map(
           oe => oe2,
           di => di2,
           do => do
        );

    -- QUESTION: signal 'do' doesn't pull up to 'H' 
        ---when oe1='0' and oe2='0'..
    -- How to fix it in VHDL to do this so that pulls up
        -- like 'tri1' signal in the Verilog version of this code.
end architecture;
```

I tried change the 'Z' in driver to 'H'... this cause synthesis to fail with a warning of multiple drivers to signal 'do'.

I tried add the line "do <= 'H';" to the top level architecture as suggested in another stackoverflow post on VHDL pullups.  Also doesn't work, synthesis fails with a warning of multiple drivers to signal 'do'.

My question is: how to get the functionality of "tri1" pullup in VHDL code to pull up signal 'do' to 'H' when its not driven and both drivers have 'Z' output.

Comment: 'H' has no meaning inside digital logic inside an FPGA, it will just converted to '1'. The problem here is you have multiple drivers on an output. It should really be inout.

Comment: Not a problem because i'm only driving the output, not reading from it.

Comment: multiple drivers are ok, as long as you set one driver to 'Z' before driving the other one with '0' or '1'.  Also, 'H' does have meaning for the IO's of an FPGA, it a "weak 1"... that's how a pullup is suppose to change the value of a 'Z' on an IO if it has a pullup. (except in VHDL I have no idea how to implement it.)  The other issue with multiple tristate drivers on an IO, is the synthesis tools are smart enough to optimize away multiple tristate buffers on an IOB such that there's only one tristate in the final netlist.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding this line in the top architecture:

`do <= 'Z' when (oe1 = '1') or (oe2 = '1') else 'H';`

Comment: yes. that works... its not quite as automated as what I was hoping for... for instance in Verilog, I just specify the signal is "tri1" and the bus automatically pulls up to "H" when its a "Z".

Answer (score 0):

```
-- implementing a pullup...
-- this appears to synthesize in vivado without multiple driver error...

-------------------------------------
-- module: pullup
-------------------------------------
library ieee;
use     ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

-- pullup
entity pullup is
   port(
       di: in  std_logic;
       dz: out std_logic
   );
end entity; 

architecture rtl of pullup is
begin
    dz <= 'H' when (di = 'Z') else di;
end architecture;

-------------------------------------
-- module: driver
-------------------------------------
library ieee;
use     ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity driver is
    port(
        oe :in  std_logic;
        di :in  std_logic;
        do :out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of driver is
begin
    process(oe, di)
    begin
        if (oe = '1') then
            do <= di;
        else
            do <= 'Z';
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;

-------------------------------------
-- module: top
-------------------------------------
library ieee;
use     ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity top is
    port(
        oe1 :in  std_logic;
        di1 :in  std_logic;
        oe2 :in  std_logic;
        di2 :in  std_logic;
        do  :out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of top is
   signal doz: std_logic;
begin

    driver1: entity work.driver
        port map(
           oe => oe1,
           di => di1,
           do => doz
        );

    driver2: entity work.driver
        port map(
           oe => oe2,
           di => di2,
           do => doz
        );

    pullup: entity work.pullup 
        port map(
           di => doz,
           dz => do
        );
    --do <= 'H' when (doz = 'Z') else doz;

end architecture;
```